# Add "Duplicate" as rejection reason for Proposed Changes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation

Currently, a Topic Request may be dismissed because the Topic already exists:

[image: dismiss topic request]

As you can see, there is even a field to paste a link to the existing Topic.

I have found that it is not just Topic Requests that can be duplicates, but also proposed changes that add a new Topic, or even some that only add a new Example. I have been using "other" as the rejection reason, and pasting the link in the field there with a note that it is a duplicate.

Some examples from [the Git docs](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/topics):

- [This new Stashing Example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/30734) was a duplicate of [this Example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/1339/stashing/4373/stashing) in the same Topic.
- [This new logging Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/23626) was a duplicate of [this existing browsing the history Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/240/browsing-the-history).
- [This new removing a submodule Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/7000) (in addition to being too specific) was a duplicate of [this Example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/306/submodules/2652/removing-a-submodule) in the Submodules Topic.

To handle these cases, I would like a "duplicate" rejection reason for proposed changes, which could allow me to paste a link to an existing Topic **or** to an Example in an existing Topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting with the next build, we're adding the Duplicate rejection reason:

> [image]

Comment: Can the URL be external? Say a topic is requested, but the official documentation already handles that specific thing very well.

Comment: @CWilson The intent here at the moment is to guard against internal duplication. If you want to propose expanding that to external URLs, please post a separate feature request.

Comment: The users also should be educated in a tour and help pages that duplication is discouraged http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330001/copied-content-should-have-automatic-consequences/330158#330158