# Copied content should have automatic consequences

Tags: feature-request, documentation, plagiarism

Today I have rejected several elegant, clever, clear, and otherwise high quality contributions to Documentation. It's the type of thing that you see in books and official websites, which is where it was taken from. Without [proper citation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

We don't want this, just like we don't want plagiarism elsewhere. There's a reason already to reject plagiarism:

> - copied content
>     Includes content that is copied from another source without proper attribution.

I'm really glad that they added a field for the URL. That was added literally yesterday (July 27, 2016).

Unfortunately, I'm not sure this is enough. If I select the option and nothing else, it will probably just get approved by the next person, who doesn't see my reject reason until after clicking approve. (Luckily, in some cases, others have noticed that the content doesn't really fit and have rejected it for other reasons. As the comments say, there are also some other people out hunting for plagiarism, which is helpful too.)

Obviously there are others with similar concerns, like [the one here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328896/what-is-currently-being-done-to-keep-plagiarists-at-bay/329025#329025). But the answer confirms there's not much in place.

---

My suggestion is:

- The URL provided by the first reviewer should be shown to all subsequent reviewers.
- Rejecting with this reason should raise an automatic moderator flag. It's already work discovering plagiarism in the first place, so the rest of the process should be as smooth as possible.
- Possibly some type of automatic ban if enough claims are brought up. (I just picture all SO mods being sleepless and spread too thin, so there should be a way for the community to handle things.)
- Also consider a similar system for the vandalism/spam reject reason

---

Related: I found this [really great tool](http://www.copyscape.com/compare.php) for comparing the differences between the proposed original and the edit. Just input both URLs and look at the differences (it also includes all the irrelevant text on both pages, but it's the best I found without rolling my own).

Comment: I can confirm. I'm only reviewing for plagiarism. When it is not plagiarized I leave the approval vote to others

Comment: FWIW, we have NO idea what the mod tools are gonna look like for this yet, but I'm currently reviewing all reports of plagiarism with an eye toward figuring that out.

Comment: Rejection reasons in general should be shown IMO. Not just specifically this one.

Comment: @rene like everybody does since the suggested edits queue.

Comment: @Shog9 - Maybe I'm dense, but is there a way at present to see all edits performed by a specific user on Documentation? We're getting flags about Documentation plagiarism by users, and I don't know how to review this like I can suggested edits.

Comment: There's a "documentation" tab in their profile that should list this, @Brad

Comment: @Shog9 - Ah, was looking at the wrong level of tabs. Is there a reason these don't show up in the "all actions" / "all" tab? That's where I thought to search for them first, since everything else appears there.

Comment: Probably more work to integrate them than could be justified right now, @Brad.

Comment: It would be interesting if the automatic process included some sort of phantom.js-like check of the text-content on the linked URL, running a diff of it against the plagiarized documentation... though, I imagine this would be extremely difficult to implement. Maybe we should ask turnitin.com how they do it?

Comment: It would be nice if reviewers could have a one click "google the proposed edit" function in order to more easily detect plagiarisms.

Comment: What about users plagiarising their own content published on some blog for instance? It's both legitimate and ethical to do this. This is also to be expected because it's likely people willing to contribute to SO Documentations already know how to write good technical content and are doing it. The current place is likely to be blogs.

Comment: @kriss: If they improve their code/examples,it's good and welcome to SO Documentation. If they just copy as is, what's the benefit? They can just provide a link to the original content.

Comment: If I may make a suggestion about plagiarism-related flags: I'd recommend suggesting edits to delete any plagiarized content or roll back any plagiarized edits, then flagging moderators on SO about it. SO moderators currently have no moderation access to Documentation, so all we can do is warn / suspend the main account. If you've tracked down instances of plagiarism, you'll be able to do as much as we can to remove them, and it would save us the effort of tracking down the source material again.

Comment: @BradLarson That's good to know. I will see about to my flag history and proposing some edits then.

Comment: Apologies for this question, but where can I mention the URL when I mark something as copied content? I have seen no place where I can put it. I just found one edit of a tag wiki where the content was hard to find. Simply 'googling' didn't turn up the copied text. I had to click through several links to find it. I also want to make it clear that I'm not blindly marking something as copied content. Other people might also try just google it and not find it and mark me as someone that incorrectly marks as copied content.

Comment: Or did I misread and concluded that by your suggestion *"The URL provided by the first reviewer should be shown to all subsequent reviewers."* that it is already possible to provide a URL?

Comment: @TT. I was talking about documentation, which is completely different than tag wikis. (Also note that I can't review tag edits yet.) But would be a good idea to add that to tag wiki edit reviewing, and I wouldn't be surprised if a FR already exists.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest the following actions:

1. Update the Documentation [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation) and help pages telling that the copying/
   plagiarism is prohibited and proper citation, when using materials
   from other place, is required. It can be done **immediately** as it is
   only text change.
2. When someone creates or edits a topic/example, similar statements should be added on the right yellowish help panels with a link to a
   help center page that explains, why copying/plagiarism is bad and
   gives guidelines for proper attribution(similar to
   https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing , but adjusted to
   Documentation). The page also should specify what penalties can be
   apply for offenders.
   It also can be done **immediately** as it is also just text change.

The further suggestions are similar to 
[Changes to discourage plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269315/changes-to-discourage-plagiarism), that was submitted 2 years ago for SO Q&A site, but looks very relevant now for  Documentation.

3. User loses X reputation if their documentation changes rejected due to copying/plagiarism or vandalism ( X should be 50+, but may be reduced or waived for the first offense).
4. Every  rejected edit due to plagiarism or vandalism should count towards a post ban.
5. Notification should be sent to the user highlighting that copying/plagiarism is not acceptable (similar to message described in [Changes to discourage plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269315/changes-to-discourage-plagiarism/269319#269319), but adjusted for Documentation).

Comment: Some of the users only have 1 rep, so I'm not sure how effective a rep penalty would be (although that's how spam flags are). I agree that the part on referencing should be more prominent. I had a hard time finding it, and I've seen some people fail at proper attribution.

Answer (score -16):

Automatic consequences? What if the licence of the original material allows it? What if the content is "plagiarised" by its original writer who also published it on a blog?

What should be forbidden is merely plagiarism of copyrighted content without consent of original writer/copyright owner.

Really I hope that Documentation will evolve one way or the other exactly the opposite: that Stack Overflow Documentation could be through some API a target among others (like PDF, epub, online Web doc, man pages, etc.) for original Documentation Publishers.

That would enormously leverage both SO Documentation (by providing high quality content to extend) and original projects Documentation (by making it high visibility, easy access).

Or course doing that on a user individual level is bad, but at large scale it's a dream.

Comment: `What if the content is "plagiarised" by its original writer who also published it on a blog ?` then there's no problem. I don't disagree Documentation might take over the world of docs one day, but at the current stage we really, really don't need content that is copied&pasted from the official docs, regardless of whether the license allows it or not.

Comment: @Pekka: we do not need individual users doing that anarchically. But if it becomes part of the normal Documentation Creation process of some projects what's the trouble ? It's like claiming for QA "Hey, we don't want Answers from those, they are well know EXPERTS!"

Comment: *What if the licence of the original material allows it ?* What the original material allows is irrelevant here. We have standards that state that material MUST be properly cited (with a link, proper block quotes, and something indicating the former is the original source of the latter).

Comment: As for self-republished content, that would only be a problem if people reject it as plagiarism. If you read what I wrote, this is not a preventative measure; the content must be rejected as "copied content" before any of these actions apply. (I do not reject as copied content if there is reason to believe the authors are the same. I leave a comment so that nobody wastes their time checking again.)

Comment: Providing a link is really no trouble. It's even advertisement for the source site. But you see, I'm contributor to some real world of some documenattion projects and copyright owner of some published material (by the way some of this material I own is also written in non english language, which raise translation issues). I'm not sure puting such advertisement on each Documenattion item would be so good. Advertisement is usually frowned upon on QA part of the site.

Comment: @Laurel: in my specific case, you may have some hard time figuring out I'm the author (I use about 6 identities for privacy reasons). I also discussed last week with a friend, who's part of a core developpement team of a programming language, about policy toward SO docs. More or less they don't have time,  but they may welcome it if someone officially do it for them (I ?). This is not some hypothetical case, it's real (I won't give more details for now before having further discussion with them).

Comment: Yes, the collaborative nature of Docs may make it hard to disclose affiliation. You should probably raise another meta question. However, if you really have all this experience with writing documentation, you likely would be able to write new content, specifically angled towards Docs. That would be the best way to do things for everyone all around.

Comment: Of course I can do, and I may. But you should understand motivations for writing docs: either it's necessary chores because I'm involved in a project or teaching a technology and I have to write missing material. But I'm doing that for the sake of the project, doing it on SO wouldn't help much. The other reason I write content is when I'm experimenting new technologies, but in that case it"s not expert content, mostly learner or advanced learner. That's the kind of original content I'm most likely to write for SO (lower quality). The other kind I would merely adapt.